# Activate windows Of file stored in an array? Type mismatch and subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, types, excel, type-mismatch, vba

I'm trying to write a couple of lines of code that activate the windows of files stored in an array so that I can copy and paste data from one file to another but I keep getting either a subscript out of range or type mismatch error. Any ideas on the syntax??

```
      Dim Allfiles as string 'array containing files that are already opened but need to be switched between one another
       Dim test as integer 'index to  Allfiles the number of files in Allfiles
         Application.workbooks(Allfiles(Test)).activate 'type mismatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post more information, such as more of your code and what you're trying to do, but some thoughts:

1. Did you include the extension in the file name string?  Workbook "MyWorkbook" should be application.workbooks("MyWorkBook.xls"), replacing xls with the proper extension for whatever version/file type you're using.
2. How are you declaring and filling the array?
3. Have you considered using a For Each on the Workbooks collection?  For example:

   ```
   Dim wkb As Workbook

   For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
       wkb.Activate
       'Do your copy/pasting here
   Next wkb
   ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140977/activate-windows-of-files-stored-in-arrays-but-getting-subscript-out-of-range-er This explains it more completely

Comment: I'm filling in the array Allfiles using a do loop. How can I include extensions for files stored in an array. All I need is the syntax, the file names stored in the allfiles array contains the complete directory of the file of interest. How should the syntax be written then for this case.

Comment: Application.workbooks(Allfiles(Test)).activate 'subscript out of range syntax error ?? Allfiles(test) where test is an integer equaling to total number of files stored in allfiles. Allfiles contain the complete directory of file of interest that need to be brought to the front.