# Activate windows of files stored in arrays, but getting subscript out of range error?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, type-mismatch, save-as

```
Sub Merge()
Dim File      As String
Dim AllFiles(), Filename As Variant
Dim count, test, StartRow, LastRow, LastColumn As Long
Dim LastCell As Variant
test = 0
ChDir "C:\" 'Insert suitable directory for your computer ex:ChDir "C:\Users\Jerry Hou\" if file of interest is in "Jerry Hou" Folder
  ReDim AllFiles(1)
Do
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    File = Application.GetOpenFilename("XML Files (*.xml),*.xml", 1, "Select File to be Merged") 'Needs to select in Order to merge files
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    If (File = "False") Then Exit Do
    ReDim Preserve AllFiles(count) 'Preserve ?
    AllFiles(count) = File 'File== file name and directory
    count = (count + 1)
    If (MsgBox("Select Another File To be Merged With?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, "Merge Files") = vbCancel) Then Exit Do
Loop  'Select Cancel in MsgBox to finish merge file(s) selection

If (count = 0) Then
    MsgBox "No selection" 'If you hit Exit from open prompt window
    Exit Sub
End If

 For count = 0 To UBound(AllFiles)
    MsgBox "User selected file name: " & AllFiles(count)

Next
 test = count
 For test = UBound(AllFiles) To LBound(AllFiles) Step -1
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=AllFiles(test)
Next

ReDim AllFiles(count)
 test = 2
Do While (test <= count)
Filename = AllFiles(test)
Workbooks(AllFiles(test)).Activate 'ERROR Brings 2nd file that the user had selected to Last xml file selected in order to Front
 'Copy and Paste TMG tab
 Sheets("TMG_4 0").Activate
 StartRow = 2
 LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
 LastCell = Cells(LastRow, LastColumn).Address 'Find lastcell of to be copied file
 Range("A2:" & LastCell).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Windows("Allfiles(1).xml").Activate 'ERROR
 Sheets("TMG_4 0").Activate
 LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 LastRow = LastRow + 1
 Range("LastRow").Select 'ERROR
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 'Copy and Paste Gamma tab
 Sheets("GammaCPS 0").Activate
 StartRow = 2
 LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
 LastCell = Cells(LastRow, LastColumn).Address
 Range("A2:" & LastCell).Select
 Selection.Copy

 Windows("Allfiles(1).xml").Activate 'ERROR Windows("File_name.xlsm").activate 
 Sheets("GammaCPS 0").Activate
 LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 LastRow = LastRow + 1
 Range("LastRow").Select 'ERROR
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 test = test + 1
Loop

Windows("Allfiles(1).xml").Activate 'ERROR

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\" & AllFiles(1) & AllFiles(test) & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You redim AllFiles but never fill it with anything.  Is there missing code?
- AllFiles is a 0 based array so if you want to start at the second element you need to use test = 1 instead of test = 2.
- For looping through an array, try this:

  `For test = 1 to ubound(AllFiles) - 1 'This loops through the array from the second element to the last`
- Is "LastRow" a named range?  If not, that's not going to work.  The following will select the last used row in a worksheet:

  `activesheet.Rows(activesheet.usedrange.rows.count).select`
- Your SaveAs is failing because 1) AllFiles looks like it's never filled and 2) your save path as you wrote would be literally: `C:\Allfile(1)&Allfiles(count)\.xlsm`.  You want:

  `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "C:\" & AllFiles(1) & AllFiles(test) & ".xlsm"`

**EDIT After Code Update**

- You never initialize your count variable, add `count = 0` to the beginning just to be safe.
- `GetOpenFilename` does in fact return the full path.  Once you have that path stored in a variable (such as AllFiles()) you can get just the filename portion with `mid(AllFiles(test), instrrev(AllFiles(test), "\") + 1)`
- You don't need the `ReDim AllFiles(count)` prior to your main Do Loop.  ReDim erases the contents of the array unless you use the Preserve keyword.
- Change `Workbooks(AllFiles(test)).Activate` to `Workbooks(Mid(AllFiles(test), InStrRev(AllFiles(test), "\") + 1)).Activate` to strip the path information and leave just the filename.
- `Windows("Allfiles(1).xml").Activate` won't work since your sending a literal string.  You want `WORKBOOKS(Mid(AllFiles(1), InStrRev(AllFiles(1), "\") + 1)).Activate` here again.
- `LastRow = LastRow + 1` probably isn't what you meant.  Try `Set LastRow = LastRow.Offset(1, 0)`
- Change `Range("LastRow").Select` to `LastRow.select`
- All instances of `Windows(` should be changed to `Workbooks(`

Comment: Thanks. But what should the syntax be for the  Windows(AllFiles(test)).Activate command?

Comment: I missed an error there.  It should be WORKBOOKS(AllFiles(test)), not Windows.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include all of the code from procedure?

Comment: I noticed that AllFiles(test) contains the COMPLETE path/directory to the file of interest. All other instances where I had used workbooks("filename.xls").activate had been where I only typed in the title of the file not the complete path. How do I only extract the title of the file? and could the problem be that the file is an xml NOT xlsm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140977/activate-windows-of-files-stored-in-arrays-but-getting-subscript-out-of-range-er

Comment: Hi Thanks for this information, its very helpful for a beginner. One more thing, I noticed that you by adding numbers at the end in:Mid(AllFiles(test), InStrRev(AllFiles(test), "\") + 1) where Mid(...+X) and X is the number of places the file name is rid of from left to right. Is there any way to get ride of the places from a file name starting from the right going left? Because I would like to be rid of the .xml ending. Its not letting me save as an .xlsm file because of that??? THanks

Comment: Or rather @Banjoe its not letting me open the completed saved as file because it says the file extension is NOT valid. How do I solve this ???

Comment: There are probably a lot better ways to handle this but a simple way is: `Replace(yourFileName, ".xml", "")`  Where yourFileName is whatever string you're removing the extension from.  That will replace any instances of ".xml" with an empty string, effectively erasing it.  Note that Replace IS case sensitive.